# Compute Engine Instance suddenly cannot be accessed from external (request timeout)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

So im having this problem recently, the domain and IP of the compute engine suddenly cannot be accessed from external (ping, ssh, request timeout) but I can still access internal SSH.

What happen and what i can do to fix this?
Im provisioning a new instance to check, and it happen again, something wrong with my network? (It happen in different area, east and northeast)

Comment: What zones have you used for your VMs? I just managed to create a new VM in asia-northeast. Please keep in mind that preemptible VMs can disappear at any time.

Comment: asia northeast too, created a second instance to test it have no problem o.O

Comment: update, it happen to the second instance too now

it seems like restarting it make the server available again, and then somehow it cant be accessed again at random time.